# Not able to fire a action on selecting a option through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to generate a div on selecting a specific option in select tag.For this i am using jquery.But i am not able to do so My code is as below:

```
<script>
    $('#categoryenv1').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === 'Fashion')
            alert("bye");
        else
            alert("hi");
    });
</script>

And my select code is as below:

<select id="categoryenv1" class="categoryenv1">
    <option value="Electronices">Electronices</option >
    <option value="Fashion">Fashion</option>
</select>
```

I have included jquery file also which works well for ready function

Can you tell me where is i am wrong?i am newbie in jquery

Comment: enclose your jquery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` block..

Comment: You need a  [$( document ).ready(function() {](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: i already have a ready function which is working perfectly but i want this action ojn selecting a option not on the page load so thats why i wrote another script

Comment: ok thanks Adam & kartikeya working fine now

Comment: this will work on option selection only don't worry about that..just include it inside ready function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>   


<script>
     $(document).delegate("#categoryenv1","change",function(e){
            if ($(this).val() === 'Fashion')
                alert("Hi");
            else
                alert("Hussy");
        });
    </script>
```

**And my select code is as below:**

```
 <select id="categoryenv1" class="categoryenv1">
        <option value="Electronices">Electronices</option >
        <option value="Fashion">Fashion</option>
    </select>
```